# Issue with sending over a JSON array and getting multiple arrays within a key - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

I have a response code that will retrieve a `JSON` object to populate a news feed (table)  The issue is when retrieving the response, if there is more than one array within a key value it gives me an error:

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c9e0f0
2014-03-08 16:46:17.830 Ripple[46433:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c9e0f0'
```

Here is the response:

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,"requested_data":
[{"name":"Admin Team","title":"Ripple","message"
:"Testing this awesome application out!"
,"time_post":"March 8"}
,{"name":"Admin Team"
,"title":"Ripple","message"
:"no","time_post":""}]}
```

Now within `requested_data` that is my main concern.  If I only have one array being put into the `requested_data` key, it works fine but it seems that when it contains more than one array it gives me that above error.  The arrays in `requested_data` are separated with a `},{`.

Again if I have the `requested_data` key only containing one array, as follow:

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,
"requested_data":{"name":"Admin Team","title"
:"Ripple","message":"no","time_post":""}}
```

It works completely fine.

Here is where it fails:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"message"];
```

Here is my `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
```

Here is my `.m` file:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = [json objectForKey:@"requested_data"];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This is how it gets the JSON and how it takes the `requested_data` object and sets it to `google...`

And it gets sent here where it crashes as stated above:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"message"];

    if([self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"message"] != NULL)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",[self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Not sure what the issue might be but I know it has to do with how it is retrieving the data from that `requested_data` `NSDictionary` and what I want it to do is only take the `message`value and than go to the next array.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: (BTW, you're not getting multiple arrays.  You're getting an array or not, based on whether there's more than one JSON object to be put into the array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes requested_data contains array, sometimes - dictionary. Probably the best way will be changing response to send array always. In case if you have only one item - send **array with one item**. So instead of

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,
"requested_data":
{"name":"Admin Team","title"
:"Ripple","message":"no","time_post":""}}
```

should be sent

```
responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,
"requested_data":
[{"name":"Admin Team","title"
:"Ripple","message":"no","time_post":""}]}
```

Replace

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
```

with

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;
```

and use it as array:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];
```

So your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];

    if([self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"] != NULL)
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",[self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Rated"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And do not forget to add `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking.count;
}
```

Comment: So the above works but the issue is when using that to populate a cell it always takes the first array no matter what.

Comment: Use `self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row]`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a behavior that some web sources have -- if there is only one item it's sent as a dictionary, if there are multiple it's sent as an array.

```
NSArray* responseArray = json[@"requested_data"];

if ([responseArray isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    responseArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:responseArray];
}

for (NSDictionary* responseString in responseArray) {
    ... Process responseString
}
```

To be a little more specific:

Change googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking to be declared as an NSArray.

Then:

```
NSArray* responseArray = json[@"requested_data"];

if ([responseArray isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    responseArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:responseArray];
}
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking = repsonseArray;
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSDictionary* place = self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = place[@"message"];
if ([place:@"message"] != NULL) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5", place[@"name"]];
...
```

Comment: you recommend me using this to check whether it is an dictionary or array?

Comment: @DavidBiga - The above code seamlessly handles both cases.  In the case of a single dictionary it's "wrapped" in an array, so the subsequent code doesn't need to know the difference.

Comment: Okay so could you show me how I would hook that up with my code above?

Comment: Well, it's a little hard to do so since your "googlePlacesArray.." is a dictionary, not an array, so it's hard to tell what you intend to do in the case of multiple elements.  Probably if you go back to the code you copied from you will discover that "googlePlacesArray.." is declared as an array, and you've chopped out array indexing that would occur on that variable.  "responseArray" above is equivalent to that "googlePlacesArray.." in the code you copied.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. [] represent Arrays and {} represent dictionaries.

So the reason it works if it only returns one object is because that object get mapped to a dictionary so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectForKey:@"message"];
```

is perfectly acceptable. But if it returns more than one object, the requested data gets mapped to an array and arrays don't respond to objectForKey:

Answer (score 1):

Calling `objectForKey` on an `NSArray` causing it to crash.

You can not assume that the response is always a dictionary. It might be an array as well.

So you need to check if it is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` before retrieving its content.

Comment: You need to update the tableview's datasource methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is as you say, an array, and when you are trying to approach it, you are using a dictionary approach instead of first an array one:

//Dictionary number 1:

{"name":"Admin Team",
"title":"Ripple",
"message":"Testing this awesome application out!"
,"time_post":"March 8"}

//Dictionary number 2"

,{"name":"Admin Team"
,"title":"Ripple",
"message":"no",
"time_post":""
}

]}

Looks like so:

```
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating: %@ of 5",
                                 [[self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:1]
                                  objectForKey:@"name"]];
```